# Nhibernate. When i call save(entity) it saves all my entities change to the DB

Tags: vb.net, hibernate, nhibernate, save

I have a vb.net app that allows users to change properties of too many objects but they can decide what to save or simply save them all. My problem is that when i change properties of a couple of objects and save one of them using this code:

```
Public Sub Add(ByRef entity As T) Implements Interfaces.ICrud(Of T).Add
     Dim session As ISession = _conection.GetSesion()
     Dim transaction As ITransaction = sesion.BeginTransaction()
     session.Save(entity)
     transaction.Commit()     
End Sub
```

The other objects persists their changes to the DB too, and i haven't call save with any of them.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's your `FlushMode` set to? If it's auto, then the session tracks and persists entity changes automatically

Comment: right now it is auto, but i had it flushmode.commit and still got the same problem

Comment: Might need more information to understand the problem... Are the objects related? If so, could the cascade rules for relationships be causing the problem?

Comment: Now that I think about it, it could be that no matter *what* `FlushMode` you use, the session is tracking the changed entities. The `FlushMode` may just control *when* the entities are persisted... **Edit**: Yep, pretty sure that's the case... You might have to change your design

Comment: Ask what you need. no objects are not related they're the same type of object with no relation between them.

Comment: How you know which objects needs to be updated?

Comment: I call that method with the exact object i need to update.

Answer (score 1):

The NHibernate's ISession maintains the identity map of the objects associated to this session (loaded, added, etc). This concept is called level-one cache.

All objects associated to a session will be saved when flush even will happen.

Comment: is there a way i can disable that behavior whitout losing the lazy loading feature?

Answer (score 1):

hazzik is right.

Flush will call an update from your associated entities if them were changed (became dirty). I'm not sure if is the best option, but you can avoid this using `session.Evict(entity)` on all objects where you don't need an update.

Read more about dirty objects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643287/nhibernate-is-there-a-way-to-mark-an-object-as-not-dirty) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhibernate-development/DQVhYM3-eQ8).

Comment: I can't do session.evict on all my entities, because the user could decide to save them later, one by one or all of them at the same time.

Comment: Just use `Merge` method to attach again the entities to the session.

Comment: After evict i used merge as you said, but, when i try to save those items later i get this exception "a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session. 388, of entity: a child of entity". To me it looks like the parent has lost its children asociation.